# Mathcad how to keep symbolic answer

Tags: mathcad

In Mathcad 15, I'm doing a simple test of the symbolic derivative for a resistor voltage divider.
`Vout(V,R1,R2):=V*R1/(R1+R2)`
`d/dv Vout(V,R1,R2)-->R1/(R1+R2)`  **<-- great!**

But when I define all three variables, it instead evaluates it numerically and turns into
`d/dv Vout(V,R1,R2)-->2/3`  **<-- not so great**

What I'd ideally like to get is both, like so:
`d/dv Vout(V,R1,R2)-->R1/(R1+R2) = 2/3`
But I can live with doing two evaluations, one for symbolic and one for numerical.

Any ideas on how to make Mathcad do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use symbolic keywords from palette

[image: substitute]

After that, Right-click on the arrow and choose hide keywords and get

[image: result]